# Jquery to serialize and submit form among several other forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

I have a page that shows several dates from different zipcodes.
I have a form and a submit button for each line and want to use jquery to serialize the info from each one and fire an ajax request to another page. So far the ajax request works but the information on the form shows "undefined". This is what I have so far:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('[name="Submit"]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tzip = $this.find('input.zip').val();
        alert (tzip);
        var zip = 'zip=' + $(this).prev('input').attr('zip').val();
        var dates = '&Date1=' + $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="Date1"]').val() + '&Date2=' + $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="Date2"]').val() + 'Date3=' + $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="Date3"]').val() + '&Date4=' + $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="Date4"]').val() + 'Date5=' + $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="Date5"]').val() + '&Date6=' + $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="Date6"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'updateZipcodes.php?',
            data: zip + dates,
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                successCallback(response);
            }
        });
        function successCallback(responseObj){
            //do something like read the response and show data 
            $('#ZipsResult').html(responseObj);
        }
    });
});
</script><table><tr>
    <th>Zipcode</th><th>Date 1</th><th>Date 2</th><th>Date 3</th><th>Date 4</th><th>Date 5</th><th>Date 6</th><th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <form id="form" name="form" >
            <th><b>20715</b><input name="zip" id="zip" type="hidden" value="20715" /></th>
            <td><input name='Date1' id='Date1' type='text' value='11-24-2014' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date2' id='Date2' type='text' value='11-26-2014' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date3' id='Date3' type='text' value='11-29-2014' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date4' id='Date4' type='text' value='11-30-2014' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date5' id='Date5' type='text' value='12-26-2014' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date6' id='Date6' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Submit' type='button' value='Submit' /></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <form id="form" name="form" >
            <th><b>20716</b><input name="zip" id="zip" type="hidden" value="20716" /></th>
            <td><input name='Date1' id='Date1' type='text' value='11-29-2014' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date2' id='Date2' type='text' value='12-01-2014' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date3' id='Date3' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date4' id='Date4' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date5' id='Date5' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date6' id='Date6' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Submit' type='button' value='Submit' /></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <form id="form" name="form" >
            <th><b>20723</b><input name="zip" id="zip" type="hidden" value="20723" /></th>
            <td><input name='Date1' id='Date1' type='text' value='11-29-2014' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date2' id='Date2' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date3' id='Date3' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date4' id='Date4' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date5' id='Date5' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Date6' id='Date6' type='text' value='' maxlength='10' size='10' readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input name='Submit' type='button' value='Submit' /></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
                    </table></br>
    <div id="ZipsResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $this = $(this);
var tzip = $this.find('input.zip').val();
```

The problem here is that $(this) here select your submit button and not your form. Therefore $this.find('input.zip').val() does not return any value since there in no 'input.zip' in your submit button. To fix the problem you should replace this line with somthing like that for example:

```
var tzip = $this.parent('form').find('input.zip').val();
```

Also always make sure your id's are unique.

Comment: I still get "undefined" with it. I have tried several other options and still no luck. I tried: '$this.parent().find('input.zip').val();' also '$this.parent().find('input[name="zip"]').val();' and others. Any other ideas ? Thanks for the explanation too !!

Comment: It works now but just partially, the zip input I can get using: `var $this = $(this);
  var tzip = $this.parent().find('#zip').val();` but the following inputs I get "undefined" again. Why ? I am using: `var date2 = $(this).parent().find('#Date2').val();` and doesn't work, also tried `var date1 = $(this).parent('form').find('#Date1').val();` any ideas ?